# Create commerce product through web services

Tags: commerce, services

I want to create products using [commerce services resource](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_services) module. At this moment, I can create a product calling the resource `.../product` with POST, but It seems that It only creates a product variations, because If I navigate to "manage products" option, I can't see the new product but if I call a GET over resource `.../product` I can see the new one.
Then, I'd tried to create a product using `.../node` resource, but I always get an error:

```
"field_product][und][form][commerce_price][und][0][amount": "Price field is required"
```

I don't know what is the right JSON structure to create a node with its product variations.
Could some one put here an example of the right JSON structure for creating node products?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error. Firstable, my drupal commerce installation hasn't `product_display` content type. I have to add it manually. I don't know why, but It's missing after clean installation. Secondly, the right JSON structure for `commerce price` section is:

```
"field_product":{ "und" :  
            {  "form": {
                   "commerce_price": {
                        "und": [ {
                           "amount": "1234.34",
                           "currency_code": "EUR",
                           "data": { "components": [] }
                            } ]
                      },
                   "sku":"eeaafe3231aa"
          }
```

After this change, I can create products display and I can see it on `product manage` page. Hope It could be useful for other who has the same problem.